# How to properly use RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, cookie-authentication

```
    namespace AspWebAppTest.Controllers
    {
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
    
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        
        ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
        bool isAuthenticated = false;

        if (userName == "Admin" && password == "pass")
        {

           
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            isAuthenticated = true;
        }
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var login = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

            return RedirectToAction("Mapping","Setting", "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        var login = HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

}
```

}

I have this Cookie Authentication Controller for my tabs(Mapping, and Config). I'am using RedirectToAction() method to redirect my return view to access mapping and config tab once the user entered the correct password and username. My problem is, after I put the password and username nothing is happening. Am I using the wrong method?

Here is my startup.cs

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `SignInAsync` method returns a `Task` which will complete when the sign-in operation has succeeded.

Your code does not `await` this `Task`, so you're sending the redirection response before the user has been authenticated.

Make your actions `async`, and `await` the results of the `Sign[In|Out]Async` methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, string password)
{
    ...
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

        return RedirectToAction("Mapping", "Setting", "Home");
    }

    return View();
}

public async Task<IActionResult) Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm not sure if I'm addressing the correct parameter in RedirectToAction(). For some reason, If I do RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") once I input the correct password and username it directs me to my main Index. I want to access the Mapping or the Config but If I switch it to ("Mapping", "Config", "Home") nothing is happening.